# Make darker areas glow

Tags: texturing

I've got a button with a warning symbol on it, and I want to animate the dark parts of that symbol to glow bright yellow. Is there a way I can texture this?

[image: Node setup]

I created the image file in photoshop, so I can change the texture file in there, but I'm not sure how I make the yellow part glow and not the red.

[image: Photoshop]

Probably I need a way to isolate the dark parts of the texture and use a mix shader or something... ugh. I'm not smart enough to figure it out.

Any help is greatly appreciated thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a black and white logo:

[image]

Use it as a *Mix Shader* factor between a *Diffuse* and a *Mix Shader* between a *Diffuse* and an *Emission*:

[image]

Move the factor of the *Mix Shader* between the *Diffuse* and the *Emission* to switch on the sign:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can make your texture into a mask by filling the symbol with white and keeping the rest of the image black. Load this mask as an image texture in your shader editor, plug it into a *math* node set to *multiply*. Plug the result into the *strength* input of an *emission* node, and plug that *emission* node into an *add shader* node. From there, you can animate the second value of the *math* node to get the effect.

You can also use a *mix shader* node. Depending on what you're looking for it might be better, but it should look more or less the same.